# Arabic number in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-10

i can't display arabic number in crystal report, Arabic number apear in Report preview(design). Arabic number converted to english in runtime mandatory,I need to dispaly it in arabic not english. I try to change in windows language sitting not work
note : this problem occur when using win 10 but when i use win 7 everythings are going well

```
        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        BL.CLSReport report = new BL.CLSReport();

        /*
        var newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-EG");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        */
        Report.RptPersent persent = new Report.RptPersent();

        persent.SetDataSource(report.data_report(ColDate.Value,txtNu.Text,txtAdDay.Text).Tables["RptPersent"]);
        Report.FRMRpt frm = new Report.FRMRpt();
        frm.CRView.ReportSource = persent;
        frm.CRView.Refresh();
        frm.Show();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        DialogResult DR= MessageBox.Show("هل تريد تقليل المده المتبقيه بمقدار 1","هااااااام",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        byte decr = Convert.ToByte(txtNu.Text);
        if (DR==DialogResult.OK &&  decr > 0)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.DayRemainder = --decr;
            txtNu.Text = decr.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: i think the problem is related with font. font may be not working with win 10, Can you use the same font in notepad or word.

Comment: i try to change font and does not respond

Comment: whatever font you are using make sure it is installed properly. to check this install the font and open notepad write something in it using the same font. As, u said this report is working in win7 but not working in win10 (_captions are missing._) it sounds like their is a case of font in-compatibility.

Comment: the report work normaly in design by arabic number in a same font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the report it self you can do a work around.... from the display string option add new formula to convert you numbers (ToText) and then replace number to Arabic numbers as follow :

```
stringVar StrArb := ToText(your field);

StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"0" , "٠" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"1" ,"١" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"2" ,"٢" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"3" ,"٣" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"4" ,"٤" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"5" ,"٥" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"6" ,"٦" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"7" ,"٧" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"8" ,"٨" );
StrArb := Replace (StrArb ,"9" ,"٩" );
```

Comment: It's wonderful but i have two problems
first i have a lot of field and reports may be 300 field that mean i will apply this solution to all one by one
second i will need to convert the result to number again to make some summation
what i can do to reduce efforts ?

Comment: i try this fun more time 
i can not convert "StrArb" to number again and i can not control on the format

Comment: Actually in your case you need to use an external tool to assist you with the conversion.

Comment: thank you i use this function but i search about better if you found else please write to me